# SQL weight multiplication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi all i have two columns in a table :

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| Units/Pk           | PackWeight/Vol |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 150g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 150g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 114g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 500g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 200g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 500g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 500g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 200g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 200g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 4.0000000000000000 | 100g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 4.0000000000000000 | 125g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 4.0000000000000000 | 125g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 1.0000000000000000 | 500g           |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

I need to multiply these together for result to replace values in PackWeight/Vol i.e. Units/Pk * PackWeight/Vol AS PackWeight/Vol.  How do i do this?  i.e. where units is 4 result would be 400g, 500g, 500g respectfully.  Other results would stay the same as units are 1.  Units/Pk is numeric and packweight is nvarchar. Thanks!

Comment: Consider putting your unit into another column and having the packweight be a numeric type like `int`. Otherwise this is going to be messy, slow, and hard to maintain

Comment: I'm selecting these from a table which I can't modify.  It may have to be messy.  Is there no way of just stripping the g/kg/L or whatever it may be, converting to numeric, multiply then convert back to nvarchar and bolt the remove text back on?

Comment: There is but it won't necessarily be clean and it almost certainly won't perform or scale very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to accomplish this, but I agree with JNK in the comments that it will scale very poorly and perform the same:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL([PackWeight/Vol], '') = '' OR PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [PackWeight/Vol]) = 0 
THEN '' 
ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING([PackWeight/Vol], 1, PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [PackWeight/Vol]) - 1)  * [Units/Pk] AS VARCHAR(256)) + 
               SUBSTRING([PackWeight/Vol], PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [PackWeight/Vol]),  LEN([PackWeight/Vol]) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [PackWeight/Vol]))
    END
        FROM table
```

Comment: Hi thank's for that, however there seems to be an error in this LEN(@a)?  I would need to declare a variable?

Comment: I have corrected this, that should have been `packweight/vol` also.

Comment: Hiya when I try to run this I'm getting conversion errors... Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. I have replaced alias columns with their actual names and have inserted below your code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The assumption I made was that the field always contains number(s) followed by letter(s)- is that correct?

Comment: So unitsizecode(packweight/vol) is nvarchar(10) and UC.packtoea(Units/Pk) is numeric and it looks like there are some blank fields in unitsizecode and some entries where there is just a 'g' on it's own... so i'm guessing if there's a new product or whatever and they don't know what the weights are yet they will be blank.

Comment: Ok- how should those values display in the output?

Comment: so if there's no value or it's just a letter etc.  i'd like it to display blank.

Comment: Edited for these cases, let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi sorry to mess you about, instead of doing this they've agreed to make my life much easier.  How do I just select just the letters from unitsizecode? i.e. so they have the source measurement l, ml, kg, g etc.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(unitsizecode, PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [unitsizecode),  LEN(unitsizecode) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', [unitsizecode]))` should do it, assuming that alphabetic characters exist in the field and that they are at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes I just came to the same answer using your code!  I have no idea how this is working though could you explain?  I know what substring does and patindex returns number of matches how is this used to return the actual alpha chars?

Comment: Sure, `PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', unitsizecode)` finds the first alphabetic character in the string and `LEN(unitsizecode) +1 - PATINDEX('%[a-Z]%', unitsizecode)` finds the length between that character and the end of the field. Translated, you get: Substring of unitsizecode starting at the first alphabetic character and ending at the end of the string.